# R and multi-columns graphic

Tags: r, graph, graphics

I'm like a newbie in R, I worked with it during my university studies, but it's far away...

I have a table with 4 columns: vine ID, and 3 columns for NDVI (a vegetation index) values at 3 dates.

```
ID 09052017 25052017 16062017
1    233      244      238
2    225      234      247
3    224      231      245
4    124      115      124
```

I know how to read my table, create variables with it, select columns or rows, make a `plot(x,y)`.

My goal is to represent for each ID a line with the 3 NDVI values and all that in a same graph windows

But i'm a little bit confused to do what I want.

Somebody can give some ideas to create this ?

Comment: you can start from [here](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2015/07/guide-data-visualization-r/) to look into visualisations in r

Comment: Please, isolate the technical problem from the business context. We do not know NDVI and are not interested in vegetation idices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  gather(date, NDVI, -ID) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = as.Date(date, '%d%m%Y'), y = NDVI, group = ID, col = factor(ID))) +
    geom_line() +
    xlab("Date")
```

[image]

Comment: Yes it's exactly that ! i'm trying, have some issues to install library. Can you explain me what does 4 last lines ? And there is no probleme if i use it on 2400 lines table ?

Comment: Before you can use a package, you have to install it. So you have to install all 3 packages first. For example: install.packages("ggplot2").

Comment: Yes it's ok, i just installed it ;)

Comment: I copy/paste your code but it's doesn't work. I imagine I have to set some objects/variables before ?

Comment: Make sure your "df" object is a data frame, with the exact same number of columns, column names, data types, and values as the example you provided in your original post. You should have absolutely no problem using it on a table with 2400 lines.

Comment: I defined df like this : `df<-p5[,1:4]` where p5 is my full table. I launched your code and it answer `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : objet 'ID' introuvable`

Comment: Are the column names in your p5 object the exact same as in the example you provided? The exact same letter cases and spelling?

Comment: Because your error message is telling me that there is no "ID" variable in your "df" object.

Comment: I resolved issue, it's a problem with date format. R do not read correctly date header from my csv.